# Bayes rule with two events

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Could someone explain this step?

$$
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:bayes}
P(A|B,C) = \frac{P(B |A,C)P(A|C)}{P(B|C)}
\end{equation}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Multiplying both sides with $P(B\mid C)P(C)$ we find:

$$P\left(A\mid B,C\right)P\left(B\mid C\right)P\left(C\right)=P\left(A\mid B,C\right)P\left(B,C\right)=P\left(A,B,C\right)\tag1$$ and:
$$\frac{P(B|A,C)P(A|C)}{P(B|C)}P\left(B\mid C\right)P\left(C\right)=P(B|A,C)P(A|C)P\left(C\right)=$$$$P(B|A,C)P\left(A,C\right)=P\left(A,B,C\right)\tag2$$

Observe that the RHS of $(1)$ is the same as the RHS of $(2)$.